# I can't get this array to filter out on click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React newb here. Basically I am simply trying to remove an array item with the handleRemove function onClick. Seems like standard procedure and most of what I've read is doing something near identical in my eyes. I've messed around with it a ton and at one point had it deleting the item, but then it wouldn't rerender, and I eventually ended up where I started. Also tried putting the handler on both li and span, but neither worked. Any help would be great, my brain is done.

````
    const guard = [
        {
            closedguard: [
                {
                    name: "Armbar",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "1",
                },
                {
                    name: "Triangle",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "2",
                },
                {
                    name: "Omaplata",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "3",
                },
            ],

    const [list, setList] = React.useState(guard);
      
    function handleRemove(id) {
    setList(list.filter((move) => move.id !== id));
        console.log(list);
    }

    return (
        <div className="guard">
            <span onClick={(e) => toggleSubMenu(e, 0)}><AddCircleIcon
             style={{ position: "relative", top: "26" }} />
             </span>{" "}
            
         <ul className="techUl">Closed Guard
                {list.map((pos) =>pos.closedguard.map((move, index) => (
                        <li
                            onClick={() => handleRemove(move.id)}
                            key={move.id}
                            className="techLi"
                            style={subMenuState[0] ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}
                            >{move.name}<span onClick={() => handleRemove(move.id)}> {move.x}</span>        
                    </li>                    
                   ))
                )}
            </ul>

            ```
````

Comment: Could you remove all code which doesn't directly relate to your issue? Aim for no more than 30 lines.

Comment: Put your console.log outside handleRemove function and check

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues with this.

Firstly, the brackets seem to be out of order for the guard constant

Secondly, the function setList is called asynchronously. This means that the setList function takes longer as compared to the other lines of code below it which will execute first. Thus, the list is logged first. If you want the console log to appear properly use the following snippet

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(list)},
[list]);
```

Thirdly, while this is fine for one update, it's recommended to use the functional process when updating state as in:

```
setList(list=>list.filter((move) => move.id !== id))
```

The difference is that this will ensure you always get the current value of state.(else it might give an older value of state which will be instantaneous but may not be the updated one)

Comment: Note that you'll have to import useEffect here

Answer (score 0):

```
    const guard = [
        {
            closedguard: [
                {
                    name: "Armbar",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "1",
                },
                {
                    name: "Triangle",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "2",
                },
                {
                    name: "Omaplata",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "3",
                },
            ],
```

You're setting `guard` as the initial state, which has one object (closedguard).
Initialize your state to `guard.closedguard`. Not sure what the point of enclosing the data is though.